# How to specify which $scope a directive uses?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a directive that is watching something on $scope, and it is getting the wrong $scope.

so I have a state setup that specifies a controller:

```
.state('app.mystate', {
    url: 'search/:searchText',
    views: {
        'mainPane@': {
            templateUrl: 'views/content/search.html',
            controller: 'ABCController'
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        searchPromise: ['$http', '$stateParams', function ($http, $stateParams) {
            console.log($stateParams.searchText);
            return $http.get(...blah...blah).then(blahblah);
        }]
    }
})
```

When this state gets activated, it goes to this view:

```
<ul ...>
    <div ng-repeat="...">
        <li ...>
            <div ng-include="'views/widgets/somewidget.html'"></div>
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

the ng-include loads this, which has a specific controller specified.  And a directive.

```
<div ng-controller="XYZController">    
    <my-chart chart="chart" ...></my-chart>
</div>
```

Here is my directive:

```
angular.module('app.directive')
  .directive('myChart', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div></div>',
      scope: {
        chart: '='
      },
    // wrong scope!
   scope.$watch('chart', function (chart) { }
```

I figured that the `<div>` that contains the my-chart directive, that directive would get the $scope that goes into XYZController.

But the directive is getting the scope that is injected into ABCController, not XYZController as I want/expected.  I can see XYZContoller getting activated.

How do I get the $scope that is injected into XYZController be the same scope that the my-chart directive sees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample code for you directive seems to have been truncated/broken during copy/paste so it's hard to see where that scope.$watch call is at. If it is in the directive definition, after the return block, then it's never getting called but I would expect it to be in the controller.

Having said that, you can specify the controller to be used by the directive in the directive attributes which would seem appropriate here, unless you want to use the directive with different scopes..

```
<div>
  <my-chart chart="chart"></my-chart>
</div>

angular.module('app.directive')
.directive('myChart', function () {
  return {
    controller: "XYZController",
    bindToController: true
    template: '<div></div>',
    scope: {
      chart: '='
    }
  })
.controller('XYZController', function($scope){
  $scope.$watch('chart', function (chart) { });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`scope: true` will create a scope that is prototypically inerited from the parent scope, so you should be able to $watch a property on the parent scope.

```
angular.module('app.directive')
  .directive('myChart', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div></div>',
      scope: true,
      link: function(scope){
         scope.$watch('chart', function (chart) { });
      });
```